# Kivy Error in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.x, camera, kivy, ubuntu-16.04

I am beginner to kivy.

Today i thought to work on the kivy camera module which is provided by the kivy official example, after running the code. I am getting the error like this.

```
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Camera_1.py", line 2, in <module>
  from kivy.app import App
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 319, in <module>
 from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 29, in <module>
 from kivy.clock import Clock
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 362, in <module>
 from kivy._clock import CyClockBase, ClockEvent, FreeClockEvent, \
ImportError: No module named 'kivy._clock'
```

I installed kivy using python3 pip and downloaded the example using official site. Please help me.

downloaded link : https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem. What I did was to remove Kivy with:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge python3-kivy
```

Then follow the following steps:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
```

Run your script with the IDLE for your python version. This worked for me!

Comment: This did not work for me, but this did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675455/6924364