# How to fix "No module named 'kivy._clock'" error in ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, kivy

I'm trying to install "kivy" (GUI lib) with Ubuntu 16.04 for Python 3.6

I tried doing the steps in the kivy official website (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux.html)

I entered in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
```

And when I tried to import:

```
from kivy.app import App
```

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'kivy._clock'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in terminal:

- Make sure you have pip installed for python3

`$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

- Uninstall python3-kivy

`$ sudo apt-get purge python3-kivy`

- Figure out your python3 version; note the first two digits:

`$ python3 -V`

Output:

> Python 3.7.3

- Find the latest build nightly build / wheels links here: https://kivy.org/downloads/ci/linux/kivy/

  Copy the link of the latest build that has a `cpXX` value in the file name that matches the first two digits of your python3 version. For me, this is `cp37`.
- Finally, put the link in the relevant section of the next command:

`$ python3 -m pip install [linkherewithoutbrackets] --user`

---

This fixed the same error for me with: Debian 10, python3 v3.7.3. This ultimately installed kivy v2.0.0rc1.

Resources should links change in the future:

- For determining compatible cython versions: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/deps-cython.html
- For the linux install instructions (and where I found the nightly wheels build link): https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux.html